# Why does "margin: 0;" trash my css?

Tags: html, css

If you look at this JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/G3N4m/

you will see that I have

```
input { margin:0; }
```

If I remove this, then the forms and radio buttons are not vertically centred any longer. So I guess it needs to be there?

If you click on "Members" a new line will appear, which ought to vertical and horizontal centred according [to](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html).

```
.rowMembers { width:60%; margin:0px auto; text-align:left; }
```

If you hover over the new line, the layout gets trashed for some reason.

`input { margin:0; }` fixes the vertical centre problem, but introduces new bugs...

Can anyone figure out why these 3 bugs occur and how to fix them?

Comment: what about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G3N4m/2/) ?

Comment: @Teneff : Amazing! What did you do? =)

Comment: @Sandra I removed the `margin: 0`, `padding` on the `.row:hover` and put `height: 100%; overflow: hidden;` on row instead of `clear: both`

Comment: @Teneff : Excellent! Can I ask a bonus question? =) Do you know why the "users and groups" line isn't horizontal centred? I have followed http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Comment: @Sandra Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G3N4m/3/) ... actually they are centered, but you will have to decrease the width of `.rowMembers`

Comment: @Sandra `text-align: center` will also work since the elements aren't floated [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G3N4m/4/)

Comment: @Teneff : Awesome! =) If you post something, then I will accept your question and close it =) Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting `overflow: hidden` and `height: 100%` on container acts as element with `clear: both` after the floated elements and it's a good quick fix :)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3N4m/4/)